# SQL view with a column that shows top result of relationship with multiple weightings

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have three tables, an **Objects** table, a **Status** table and a **StatusTypes** Table.

An Object has Multiple Status' which each has a status type. I would like to create a view that gives me the objects **ID**, and Most Important Status **Description** which is found in the StatusTypes table, and the most important status **Date** which is in the Status Table.

The part I am getting hung up on is to find the most Important Status It must first be sorted by the latest date, then by a integer weighting (**Priority**) in the Status Table then again by another weighting in the StatusTypes Table (**Weighting**)

What would be the best SQL statement to quickly deliver these results.

#### Objects

```
ID  Aquisiton Date  Serial Number
127237  1997-04-21  2151513515
127239  1997-10-31  2151513523
127242  1998-01-20  2165588481
127272  1998-10-20  2195689842
127286  1999-06-15  2231549489
127291  1999-06-01  2229564978
```

### Status

```
ID  ObjectID    Priority    StatusMessage   Date                Status
1   127237         1        Online          22.02.12 07.01.00   1
2   127237         3        Job Received    22.02.12 07.01.00   3
3   127237         5        Job Started     22.02.12.07.01.00   3
4   127237         5        Jam             22.02.12.07.01.00   2
5   127286         1        Online          22.02.12.07.09.00   1
```

### Status Types

```
ID  Description Weighting
1   Idle        0
2   Error       9
3   Working     5
```

### Expected Output##

```
ID      Status      Date        
127237  Error       22.02.12 07.01.00
127286  Idle        22.02.12.07.09.00
```

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful.

Comment: Extending @GoatCO comment, it should be in a tabular format and involve both, current data and also expected data. If there is no data currently then make it up :)

Comment: Added example data Above

Comment: Updated answer using your data.  Expected output isn't produced since ID 127286 isn't included in sample data, but shows properly for the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you could use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC, Priority, Weighting) 'RowRank'
      FROM YourTable a
     )sub
WHERE RowRank = 1
```

Obviously replacing `YourTable` with the relevant `JOIN`'s

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function assigns a number to each row. `PARTITION BY` is optional, but used to start the numbering over for each value in that group,  ie: if you `PARTITION BY ID`  then for each unique ID value the numbering will start over at 1.  `ORDER BY` of course is used to define how the counting should go, and is required in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

**Updated with your data:**

```
SELECT ObjectID,Description,Date
FROM (SELECT a.*,b.Description,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ObjectID ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE,LEFT([Date],8),4) DESC, Priority DESC, Weighting DESC) 'RowRank'
      FROM Status a
      JOIN Status_Types b
        ON a.Status = b.ID
     )sub
WHERE RowRank = 1
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9758d/10/0)

Comment: Great Thanks, That SQL Fiddle is fantastic thank you. I was able to 'Fiddle' and extend the code further.